# KeyEvent Constants in Java

Tags: java, constants, keyevent

I came across this code:

```
    private boolean right = true;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    int key = e.getKeyCode();

                    if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!right)) {
                        left = true;
                        up = false;
                        down = false;
                    }

    }
```

From my understanding, the getter method called getKeyCode returns a key in integer form. Does a programmer necessarily have to understand the actual numerical value of KeyEvent.VK_LEFT? Or should I treat it as a black box and not care and worry about how it is implemented and just use it?

Apparently the value associated with VK_LEFT is 37 after looking at the Java API.

Comment: Yes, to the last part of your question :)

Comment: _what is this actual integer numerical value associated with VK_LEFT?_ Did you try System.out.println("KeyEvent.VK_LEFT value: " + KeyEvent.VK_LEFT); ????

Comment: Ah, I actually did not think about that! But I check the Java API and it says 37.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point about those constants is that you don't have to know the actual numeric value. You could get it easily with a `println` but you shouldn't (you're not ensured the value won't change in a future release).

Treat them as black boxes.

Comment: Thanks I never knew I can treat key constants as a black boxes too. I always thought that was just for methods.

Answer (score 1):

Never worry about associated value for any keys. Just use [`KeyEvent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.java) class static variables.

```
 public static final int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
```

Comment: what is 0x25? a hexadecimal? I checked the Java API and it says the constant is 37. How come you posted 0x25?

Comment: added link too just click key event. 37 is dec for hex 25